# Android Jetpack：How to combine the Paging with Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging

I'm using Paging3. And I have a local database, here is a DAO function.

```
    public PagingSource<Integer, Item> getPagingItems();
```

I want to know, how to sse this PagingSource to display data to Recyclerview. And It can change with the data in the database. What should I do?

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#display-paged-data ? Anything I can clarify from the code example there?